# Why I get the error? Overloaded operator []

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, templates

When I try to write code like this, I get this compile error. In fact, the operator [ ] is overloaded.
I'm confused, anybody can help me?

```
AssocArray<int, int> ary;
ary.addItem(1, 1);
ary.addItem(2, 1);
ary.addItem(3, 1);
ary.addItem(4, 1);
ary.addItem(5, 1);
ary[5] = 2;//error occur here
```

Here is error message:

```
error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
...could be 'int &opt::AssocArray<key,value>::operator [](key &)'
with
[
    key=int,
    value=int
]
while trying to match the argument list '(opt::AssocArray<key,value>, int)'
with
[
    key=int,
    value=int
]
```

The implementation of AssocArray is as follows(Notes: it locates in *.h file):

```
    template <typename key, typename value>
    class AssocArray
    {
    public:
        typedef typename std::pair<key, value> type;

        bool addItem(key& k, value& v);

        bool addItem(key k, value v);

        bool isItem(key& k);

        value& operator[] (key& k);

        typename std::vector<type>::iterator begin()
        {
            return vecData.begin();
        }

        typename std::vector<type>::iterator end()
        {
            return vecData.end();
        }

    protected:
    private:
        std::vector<type> vecData;
    };

    template <typename key, typename value>
    bool AssocArray<key, value>::addItem( key k, value v )
    {
        if(isItem(k)) return false;

        vecData.push_back(std::make_pair(k, v));
        return true;
    }

    template <typename key, typename value>
    value& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(vecData.begin(), vecData.end(),
            [&](type& param)
        {
            return param.first == k;
        }
        );
        if(vecData.end() != iter)
            return iter->second;

        value v;
        vecData.push_back(std::make_pair(k, v));
        return vecData.rbegin()->second;
    }

    template <typename key, typename value>
    bool AssocArray<key, value>::isItem( key& k )
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(vecData.begin(), vecData.end(),
            [&](type& param) mutable -> bool
        {
            return param.first == k;
        }
        );

        return vecData.end() != iter;
    }
```

Comment: Your `operator[]` is declared to take a reference, but you pass it a literal `int`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that would result in linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator[] is declared to take a non-const lvalue reference:

```
template <typename key, typename value>
value& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )
```

But the argument you pass is `5`, which is a literal and therefore an rvalue.

Since the implementation of the operator does not seem to modify the key, I suggest that you change the declaration so it takes a const lvalue reference:

```
template <typename key, typename value>
value& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( const key& k )
```

This can bind to an rvalue, and all will be fine.

Comment: it did work, thank you very much. i shouldn't have made this mistake.